Ionic - How prevent dynamic fontsize on specific component?
I use dynamic fontsize from ionic. I set the dynamic fontsize on the <html> tag with the property
html {
  --ion-dynamic-font: var(--ion-default-dynamic-font);
}

But then i have the Problem, that my <ion-toolbar> in <ion-header> also scale the font, and i want to prevent this.
I tried to set this to <ion-toolbar>
ion-toolbar {
  --ion-dynamic-font: unset;
}

I tried also initial. But did not work. Is this even possible?
Kind Regards.

try inherit else just give var(--ion-default-dynamic-font) !important

@NarenMurali Does not work :(

The best solution for allowing Ionic to support Dynamic Font Scaling but tweaking it for individual components seems to be CSS clamp.
For example, this constrains the effect of Dynamic Font Scaling to within the range 12-18px on ion-title:
ion-title {
    font-size: clamp(12px, 100%, 18px);
}

You don't need to unset or override --ion-dynamic-font.
